# How does django jwt sign the jwt token?

Tags: python, django, jwt

When using `https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt`, how is the JWT request signed? Does it use the django secret-key in the settings.py file or how specifically does it sign the requests? Is there a way to provide a provide a private key file for this, or what are the requirements for singing the jwt request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

}
```

These are the available [settings](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) in drf jwt.

Here you can see **JWT_SECRET_KEY** setting. You can specify custom secret here.

> **JWT_SECRET_KEY** This is the secret key used to sign the JWT. Make sure
>   this is safe and not shared or public.
>
> Default is your project's settings.SECRET_KEY.